# Symfony2 Routing parameters

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller

I am new to symfony2 and MVC in general. I am going through the documentation for Symfony and I am in the chapter on Routing.

I am getting confused with the annotation

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog/{slug}", name="blog_show")
 */
public function showAction($slug)
{
    // ...
}
```

I understand that if user visits blog/xxx, the showAction will be called. What I do not understand is why there is name="blog_show" after the comma in the @Route.

Could someone please describe why we use it?

Comment: Please accept it as valid if you think that was useful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is just an Alias for this route

This name is the one that you have to call for example from twig

```
<a href="{{ path('blog_show', {'slug': my-blog-post}) }}" ...
```

It will call /blog/my-blog-post

Or if you want to redirect to this address

```
return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('blog_show'), array('slug' => 'my-blog-post'));
```

Or generate URL

```
$url = $this->generateUrl('blog_show', array('slug' => 'my-blog-post'));
```

Here you have the documentation

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#redirecting

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-pages

Comment: Cool, thanks, that seems to make sense. I can't test it out right now but seems to be right judging by the docs. I will mark it  as valid.